# I would like to create a pin-code dialogue, like the one you can switch on to dial on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, security

I am new to coding and would like to set this up in my app. How or where do you start this process... In you AppDelegate file? Please provide me a jump start. I'm invoking this process from the UIButtonTypeInfoDark on the NavgationBar/TabBar Controller from the MainWindow. I am basically trying to set up a 4 digit pin to protect the users privacy within the app. I would like to create a pin-code dialogue, like the one you can switch on to dial on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a text field, and set its keyboard type to "number pad"